# Codeigniter Cms Login Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

I've been following this tutorial by Envato on Tutplus: https://tutsplus.com/course/build-a-cms-in-codeigniter/

I'm at the part at which were are securing the login and i've followed the tutorial exactly.

Here is the page http://division96.com/admin/user/login

here is the application folder https://mega.co.nz/#F!z84URZJZ!GmtYxS0UkR9fqS5GBOVY7Q

The problem is it seems to be not getting the userdata, from what i can see.

I know its not much detail but i'm not sure what would be the best way to get the info that is required. If you need any more info just comment!

Denver

Comment: do you have a test user/pass that we could try?

Comment: it suppose to denverjbarr@gmail.com pass should be denver

Comment: is it possible i did not hash the password correctly? i put the pass 

denver then the encryption key into a sha512 hasher http://www.hashemall.com/

Comment: Possibly, but we need to find out what the query is doing. Can you turn on profiling?  Just add `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in the constructor of the controller - or at the top of the `login` method.  This way, we can see the actual query that is getting executed by the database.

Comment: Oh, but you'll also need to comment out those `redirect` calls on lines 18 and 22 of `/application/controllers/admin/user.php`

Comment: Well, try to log in and then check to see if the password in SQL statement matches that in your database.

Comment: hmm i dont think so, how do you hash a password?

Comment: I guess i should say I think the password looks the same as it does in phpmydadmin but i think it might be the way i was getting the encrypted version, how would you encrypt a password for codeigniter with the encryption key?

Comment: You use the [Encryption Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html)  ::  `$this->encrypt->encode($raw_password);`

Comment: i'm not sure how you would do that?

Comment: Well, the password is getting encrypted (you can see that in the sql and phpmyadmin).  Maybe you should delete that user and register again? I'm guessing the encryption key was changed after you registered that user, then after adding the encryption key - the encryption doesn't match anymore.

Comment: when adding the user would you just put the password or would you use hash it?

Comment: You definitely want the hashed password in the database. So, normally, you hash the password and insert that into the database. Then, when you need to authenticate, you take the password from the form input, hash that (the same way you hashed previously), and then check to see if the hashed passwords are the same.

Comment: so when creating a user in phpmyadmin how would you go about hashing that password?

Comment: You don't. You ad the user through the registration methods of the codeigniter site.

Comment: You lost me with that one?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use encryption_key

```
INSERT INTO users (email, password, name) VALUES ('user.user@name.pro', 
     SHA2('optimusprime**ENCRYPTION_KEY**',512), 'Optimus');
```

for user pass when you followed mysql steps? If not just rewrite hash method in user_model.php like this:

```
public function hash ( $string ) {
     return hash('sha512', $string);
}
```